# Convert unix timestamp to date in java

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

How can I convert minutes from Unix timestamp to date and time in java? For example, timestamp `1372339860` correspond to `Thu, 27 Jun 2013 13:31:00 GMT`.

I want to convert `1372339860` to `2013-06-27 13:31:00 GMT`.

Edit: Actually I want it to be according to US timing GMT-4, so it will be `2013-06-27 09:31:00`.

Comment: `DateTime whatever = new DateTime(yourunixtimestampaslong * 1000L, DateTimeZone.UTC);` if you use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  Or `DateTime whatever = new DateTime(yourunixtimestampaslong * 1000L, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-4));` for your second example.  Javadoc [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Comment: `private String getDateString(long timeInMilliseconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        return formatter.format(timeInMilliseconds);
    }`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can use SimlpeDateFormat to format your date like this:

```
long unixSeconds = 1372339860;
// convert seconds to milliseconds
Date date = new java.util.Date(unixSeconds*1000L); 
// the format of your date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
// give a timezone reference for formatting (see comment at the bottom)
sdf.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

The pattern that `SimpleDateFormat` takes if very flexible, you can check in the javadocs all the variations you can use to produce different formatting based on the patterns you write given a specific `Date`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

- Because a `Date` provides a `getTime()` method that returns the milliseconds since EPOC, it is required that you give to `SimpleDateFormat` a timezone to format the date properly acording to your timezone, otherwise it will use the default timezone of the JVM (which if well configured will anyways be right)

Comment: Modified, thanks @fvu

Comment: this answer is better, because author also give an example how to respect time-zones.

Comment: Excellent! Btw to get current time zone of the device we can use `TimeZone.getDefault()`

Comment: When not specified, default timezone is used anyways

Comment: Which package do I have to import for `Date`? Visual Eclipse gives me several options for Java 8, and none of them work: `sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar`, `sun.util.calendar.LocalGregorianCalendar`, `java.util` and `java.sql`

Comment: @Nicolas: I'm assuming you've figured it out by now but java.util.Date is what is used in this example along with java.text.SimpleDateFormat. If you're using Java 8 you can use the below example (Instant.ofEpochSecond) but be aware it requires Android O as well.

Comment: @Nicolas I just added the package namespaces for the clases used.

Comment: @DavidHofmann, if i use default time will it change time for different countries?

Answer (score 41):

Java 8 introduces the [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) utility method for creating an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from a Unix timestamp, this can then be converted into a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and finally formatted, e.g.:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

final long unixTime = 1372339860;
final String formattedDtm = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTime)
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"))
        .format(formatter);

System.out.println(formattedDtm);   // => '2013-06-27 09:31:00'
```

I thought this might be useful for people who are using Java 8.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

Comment: Your example of an offset-from-UTC (`GMT-4`) is more appropriate to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) than `ZonedDateTime`. Also, I suggest you break out your example code into pieces to introduce each step and each idea separately.

Answer (score 12):

You need to convert it to milliseconds by multiplying the timestamp by 1000:

```
java.util.Date dateTime=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);
```

Comment: note that the question is to convert epoch minutes to date, and then formtat it to a pattern with a timezone offset