# Convert unix/epoch time to formatted date - unexpected date

Tags: android, timestamp, android-date

Im trying to convert a timestamp to a human readable date and time. I tried:

```
String dateSt = 1386580621268;
Log.i("*****", "date st is = "+dateSt);
long unixSeconds = Long.parseLong(dateSt);
Log.i("*******", "unix seconds is = "+unixSeconds);
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // the format of your date
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

The expected result is to be `09-12-2013`, however i get `28-12-45908`. The above example can be found at: [Convert Unix timestamp to date java, answer by David Hofmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1386580621268` is not a unix timestamp i.e. seconds since epoch for 9-12-2013 but milliseconds since epoch. Remove the `*1000L` or divide the input by 1000.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you very much for clearing that up. It works correctly now :) I just removed the `*1000L` like you suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

Try this,

```
public static String Epoch2DateString(long epochSeconds, String formatString) {
    Date updatedate = new Date(epochSeconds * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
    return format.format(updatedate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this way.

```
public static String Epoch2DateString(String epochSeconds) {
    Date updatedate = new Date(Integer.parseInt(epochSeconds) * 1000L);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return format.format(updatedate);
}
```