# How convert the UTC time to format date?

Tags: android

I get time from location, it return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

```
 long gpstime = location.getTime();
```

EX: `gpstime =1395477208249`

How convert to format `"yyyyMMddhhmmss"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct a `Date` object with the [`Date(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor.
2. Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format to string with your format pattern.

Comment: Can you see this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576049/gallery-has-stopped-while-cropping-image-in-kitkat-nexus7??

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date(gpstime); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: refercence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java

Answer (score 1):

First of all just want to make sure that location.getTime() will return the time of the fix, not the current time.  You can convert to local with:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timezone = calendar.getTimeZone();

SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
formattedDate.setTimeZone(timezone);
```