# Gallery has stopped while cropping image in kitkat Nexus7

Tags: android, gallery, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-7

***Problem:*** 
I am fetching image from gallery and after that cropped that image and its working perfect in all device. But it is giving me error while running in Nexus 7 kitkat since i have checked build version for it with "Gallery Stopped" error. I have implemented code and all other neccessary permission in manifest file still not getting response. So can anybody resolve this?

***Here is my Code:***

```
 final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
            "Select from gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                // camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { // pick from file

                Intent intent;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,

                    "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
                /*
                 * Intent intent = new Intent();
                 * 
                 * intent.setType("image/*");
                 * intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 * 
                 * startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                 * "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                 */
            }
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    btnTakephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
        doCrop();

        break;

    case PICK_FROM_FILE:

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

        } else {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
            try {
                parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver()
                        .openFileDescriptor(mImageCaptureUri, "r");
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor
                        .getFileDescriptor();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        doCrop();

        break;

    case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            myBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

        }

        File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        Intent n = new Intent();
        n.setClass(getApplicationContext(), EffectsActivity.class);
        n.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
        startActivity(n);
        break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        }

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 350);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 350);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

***CropAction:***

```
 public class CropOption {
  public CharSequence title;
  public Drawable icon;
  public Intent appIntent;
 }
```

***CropOptionAdapter.java***

```
public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
    super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

    mOptions = options;

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

    CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

    if (item != null) {
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon))
                .setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name))
                .setText(item.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    return null;
}
    }
```

Comment: No no error in logcat. Just Gallery stopped dialog.

Comment: put try catch in `onActivityResult` & `doCrop` & `getView` and put `e.printstack()` that will give you exact bug in your logcat.

Comment: why are you using `ACTIOP_OPEN_DOCUMENT` for API 19? could you try with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` as you did for below API level...

Comment: I have changed still problem is same.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I have tested and got no problems...

Comment: @GopalRao In which Kitkat version??

Comment: I have tested in some devices which is working fine but only in nexus 7 with kitkat version

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA presently I don't have device with me. but I have tested in emulator with Android 4.4.2 version. its working fine... emulator is 3.4" WQVGA (240 X 432) ldpi

Comment: @GopalRao You'r right. But you know that we are just depending on real device. Thanks for your info

Comment: but if Gallery is stopped, then there is problem with that app. app is not handling all execptions...

Comment: @GopalRao You are right. But how can i solve this? If this app is not handling this so is there any solution particular for that?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA You are not creator of that Gallery app right. then what you can do? the problem is with that app, not with your app...

Comment: @GopalRao Ya it will be.. it is also working in emulator. I have checked that.

Comment: @GopalGopi  Thanks buddy, I need one help yar. Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432781/display-curve-shape-progress-in-custom-view?noredirect=1#comment48953994_30432781

Comment: @GopalGopi Did you check it ? I wanna that one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To resolve the problem what i have done is to,

just change the code from this

```java
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(
    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE
);
```

to

```java
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(
    android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri
);
startActivityForResult(
    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE
);
```

Working like charm.