# Camera API working on Jelly Bean but not Kitkat

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a really strange problem. The following code I have is used to take a picture on button click. It works properly on Jelly Bean phones, but not on Kitkat:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.takepic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MakePhotoActivity";
  private Camera camera;
  private Button capture = null;
  private int cameraId = 0;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  capture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.captureBack);
  capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         camera.startPreview(); //After this, nothing gets printed, and picture does not get taken
        System.out.println("Camera preview has started.");
            camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    }
});
// do we have a camera?
if (!getPackageManager()
    .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
} else {
  cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
  if (cameraId < 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No back facing camera found.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
    camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
  }
}
  }



 private int findBackFacingCamera() {
int cameraId = -1;
// Search for the front facing camera
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
  CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
  Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
  if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
    cameraId = i;
    break;
  }
}
return cameraId;
}

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
if (camera != null) {
  camera.release();
  camera = null;
}
super.onPause();
 }

}
```

**PhotoHandler.java**:

```
package com.example.takepic;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

  private final Context context;

  public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

   File pictureFileDir = getDir();
  Toast.makeText(context, "Entered onPictureTaken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

  Log.d("Directory error", "Can't create directory to save image.");
  Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return;

 }

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

File pictureFile = new File(filename);

try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
  fos.write(data);
  fos.close();
  Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception error) {
  Log.d("File saving error", "File" + filename + "not saved: "
      + error.getMessage());
  Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

  private File getDir() {
  //  File sdDir =    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
 File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
 Toast.makeText(context, ("Path : "+sdDir.getAbsolutePath()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return sdDir;
 }
}
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.takepic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.takepic.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have put quite a few toast messages and print statements for debugging purposes. I have not posted logcat here, because, when I run this on a KitKat phone, **I get nothing on logcat**. No exception or warning.

When I run this on a **jellybean** phone, it runs properly, displaying all the toasts and prints and takes the picture.

When I run this on **Kitkat**, I do not get any debugging messages after the

```
camera.startPreview();
System.out.println("Camera preview has started.");
```

I suspect problem is with the takePicture API, but I am unable to debug it.

### Edit

After further analysis, I found the reason for issue. The **PhotoHandler** object gets invoked successfully, but the *onPictureTaken* method is not called, probably because it did not get information that picture was clicked by the camera. I don't know why.

Comment: Check below link help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576049/gallery-has-stopped-while-cropping-image-in-kitkat-nexus7

Comment: My problem is not with gallery.. its most likely with the takePicture API. Moreover I don't get any exceptions like in that post.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and single-stepping through it to see where it goes?

Comment: No I have not.. could you please give me a link telling me how I could do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have observed that you are not assigning any surface holder to the camera. Giving a preview surface to the camera is important.

According to the docs here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

follow the code suggested by the doc. Taking a picture without a preview is a big security concern. Android guys might have fixed this in kitkat.

You might have missed that part of the code while pasting here so as an added concern also check that you are executing your code 'camera.takePicture(null,null,callback)' inside the callback method 'onSurfaceCreated' of SurfaceHolder.

You can get all the relevant code at aforementioned link.

Comment: Your link helped a lot :) The main mistake I made was not assigning a surface holder. Apparently this is a necessity for Kitkat phones, while it works without it in JB phones.. thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

KitKat's garbage collection works differently than previous APIs.

I'm guessing that the `PhotoHandler` object that you pass to the `takePicture()` method is getting garbage collected before `onPictureTaken` can be called.

Try making a `PhotoHandler` object as in instance variable in your `MainActivity`.

At the top of the class:

```
PhotoHandler photoHandler;
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

Then when you call `takePicture()`:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, photoHandler);
```

Comment: I tried your approach, it doesn't work. When you say "at the top of the class" for PhotoHandler, do you mean as a class member or *outside* the class?

Comment: class member - they are called instance variables in java

Comment: The fact that this is only happening on KitKat makes me 99% sure that something is getting garbage collected too early.  Could be the OnClickListener, for example.  It's up to you to figure that out with a debugger and break points or a bunch of logs telling you if something is null when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Matt Logan can you please help me regarding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714771/android-camera-take-picture-failed-issue

Answer (score 1):

Add `uses-feature` in your manifest file :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

and check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). It might be help you.