# How do redirect to Splunk search page? Getting "Invalid earliest_time"

Tags: redirect, search, splunk

How do redirect my web page to the Splunk search page? Getting "Invalid earliest_time"

i want to redirect my web page to splunk search page

I'm using this URL:

http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/en-US/app/xxxx/search?earliest=05/11/2015:16:44:28&latest=05/11/2015:16:46:15&q=search%20YYG3XVJEU5D2RIX236HPJBFDBI

But I keep getting "Invalid earliest_time".

When I perform the search in Splunk search page, I see this URL in the browser:
http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/en-US/app/xxxx/search?earliest=1431351868&latest=1431351975&q=search%20YYG3XVJEU5D2RIX236HPJBFDBI&sid=1447753829.853723

My question is, how does Splunk transform this earliest=05/11/2015:16:44:28 To earliest=1431351868?
I'm working with Java. I tried sending the date long value in the request, but still got the same error...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the documentation from here:

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/Search/Specifytimemodifiersinyoursearch
[Convert unix time stamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)