# ZonedDateTime as PathVariable in Spring REST RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a REST endpoint in my Spring application that looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/device/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Page<DeviceInfo> getDeviceListForCustomerBetweenDates(@PathVariable ZonedDateTime startDate, @PathVariable ZonedDateTime endDate, Pageable pageable) {
    ... code here ...
}
```

I have tried passing in the path variables as both milliseconds and seconds. However, I get the following exception both ways:

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.time.ZonedDateTime for value '1446361200'; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1446361200' could not be parsed at index 10"
```

Can someone please explain how I can pass in (either as seconds or milliseconds) a String such as 1446361200 and get it to convert to ZonedDateTime?

Or is the only way to pass as String and then do the conversion myself? If so is there a generic way to get this handled for multiple methods with similar design?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is relatively new and Spring likely hasn't been updated to support it directly.  See JasonZ's answer for a workaround for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a default converter for `ZonedDateTime` parameters. It uses Java 8's `DateTimeFormatter` created like

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
```

This could've been any `FormatStyle` or really any `DateTimeFormatter` as far as you're concerned, your example wouldn't have worked. `DateTimeFormatter` parses and formats to date strings, not timestamps, which is what you've provided.

You could have provided an appropriate custom [`@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) to your parameter such as

```
public Page<DeviceInfo> getDeviceListForCustomerBetweenDates(
    @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime startDate, 
    @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime endDate, 
    Pageable pageable) { ...
```

or with an appropriate [`pattern`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) and a corresponding date string like

> 2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00

You won't be able to do any of the above with a unix timestamp. [The canonical way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java) to do timestamp to `ZonedDateTime` conversion is through [`Instant#ofEpochSecond(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-), given an appropriate `ZoneId`.

```
long startTime = 1446361200L;
ZonedDateTime start = Instant.ofEpochSecond(startTime).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(start);
```

To make this work with `@PathVariable`, register a custom `Converter`. Something like

```
class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {
    private final ZoneId zoneId;

    public ZonedDateTimeConverter(ZoneId zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
        long startTime = Long.parseLong(source);
        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(startTime).atZone(zoneId);
    }
}
```

And register it in a [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) `@Configuration` annotated class, overriding [`addFormatters`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addFormatters-org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry-)

```
@Override
protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new ZonedDateTimeConverter(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
}
```

Now, Spring MVC will use this converter to deserialize the `String` path segment into a `ZonedDateTime` object.

---

In Spring Boot, I think you can just declare a `@Bean` for the corresponding `Converter` and it will register it automatically, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 5):

You gonna need to accept what you passed to `@PathVariable` as a `String` data type, then do the conversion yourself, your error logs pretty clearly tells you that.

Spring library cannot conver String values"1446361200" to `ZonedDateTime` type through `@PathVariable` binding unfortunately.

Comment: You're right about what has to be done, but this is about Spring conversion, not Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `@PathVariable` only supports a limited set of types including the 7 basic types (`boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`)  plus `Date`.

However, it is possible to [extend that](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) using [an `@InitBinder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) in your controller and adding a binding for `ZonedDateTime.class`.  I'm not sure if you can define this in an external class, though... if not, you need to define this `@InitBinder` in every controller that uses a `ZonedDateTime`.

Edit: You may need to create a custom [`PropertyEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html) and bind it using `registerCustomEditor` to do this.