# Date and time using openweathermap api

Tags: java, android

`"dt":1427700245`
How I change this date format into `17-Mar-2017 13:40`

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(weatherResponse.getDt()*1000));
            date.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

It shows me `25 Jan 1969 01:52:28`

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Java `new Date(1427700245 * 1000)` gave `Wed Jan 21 12:58:22 CET 1970`. Also `17-Mar-2017 13:40` would correspond to something around `1489671600` seconds since the epoch depending on time zone. Certainly not 1427700245.

Comment: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_489_738_200L).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT))`. Gave `17/03/17, 1:40 PM`. Excat output will depend on time zone and locale.

Answer (score 1):

The openweather API documentation states that the date format is in Unix UTC format.

https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3

Here's an answer on SO that describes how to convert the Unix timestamp date:

[Convert unix timestamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

so your date 1427700245 is 2015-03-30 03:24:05 (GMT-04:00).

```
    long unixSeconds = 1427700245;
    // convert seconds to milliseconds
    Date date = new java.util.Date(unixSeconds*1000L); 
    
    // the format of your date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
    // give a timezone reference for formatting (see comment at the bottom)
    sdf.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); 
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

EDIT: using DateTimeFormatter which is also included in the above mentioned SO post.

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        final long unixTime = 1427700245;
        final String formattedDtm = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTime)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"))
                .format(formatter);

        System.out.println(formattedDtm);   // => 2015-03-30 03:24:05
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: @Ole V.V. - thank you for your feedback... the alternative solution using DateTimeFormatter has been added to the answer

Comment: Using `DateTimeFormatter`, `Instant` and `ZoneId` is strongly encouraged and recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Its precision issue. Explicitly define you date value as long.
It will work then

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy'T'HH:mm"):
String dateString = sdf.format(weatherResponse.getDt()*1000):
date.setText(dateString):
```