# Converting UNIX TimeStamp in Android API versions LESS than 24

Tags: android, unix-timestamp

I am developing an app which I want specifically to work Android API 23. I need to convert a UNIX timestamp into an actual time/date.

I have seen this solution which mentions SimpleDateFormat;

[Convert unix time stamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

However, this is only supported in API 24 and higher. Any ideas on how to achieve this in API 23?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` [has been around since API Level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in general, and AFAIK all of those characters in the format string have as well.

Comment: Read second line of the code in the [answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433005/5221149): `new Date(unixSeconds*1000L)`. You have now converted the `unixSeconds` value into an **actual time/date**. The `java.util.Date` class *is* an actual time/date. `Thu, 27 Jun 2013 13:31:00 GMT` is not an actual time/date, but one *(of many)* text representations of an actual time/date.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. You are correct, it is a duplicate of that, I was unaware I was using android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat instead of java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you may be using `android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat` instead of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The former one was added in API level 24, the later one should work fine for all API levels.